# ¿Cómo podría agregar una variable desde mi controllador a mi etiqueta <style>?

Tags: css, laravel

llevo una hora mirando foros de como agregar una variable desde mi controlador a mi etiqueta  de mi vista.
He comprobado que los datos que estoy enviado desde mi controlador son correctos pero necesito agregarlos de esta manera:

```
    <style>
html{
          background-image: url(/images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_diploma/{{$nombre_proyecto[0]->titulo_proyecto}}/{{$imagen_diploma[0]->nombre}});
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-attachment: fixed;
          background-position: center center;
          background-size: 100%;
          margin: 0px;
     }
</style>
```

Pero no acaba de funcionar...

Comment: Es un archivo .css ese pedazo de código? Una posibilidad es agregarlo en el index dentro de la etiqueta `<style>`.

Comment: Está dentro de la etiqueta <style>

Comment: Que es lo que no funciona? Muestra como queda esa url en el navegador una vez que se carga la pagina

Comment: probaste colocando la URL en un <img /> para probar que realmente este la ruta bien construida.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ la url queda así http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_diploma/Proyecto 1/diploma2.jpg. Aún así no muestra la imagen, pero si lo pongo a mano si la muestra...

Comment: @JeanCarlosGarcia si lo he probado y lo muestra pero si lo añado de esta forma no la muestra.

Comment: `Proyecto 1` tiene un espacio, quizá sea eso, prueba con el helper url: `background-image: url( {{ url('/images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_diploma/' . $nombre_proyecto[0]->titulo_proyecto . '/' . $imagen_diploma[0]->nombre) }} );`

Comment: Tampoco me ha funcionado